# repeat function adding values if remainder of sum is less than defined number

Tags: python

first post here and sorry if this has been asked before but my searching turned up nothing (maybe I was using the incorrect search terms). I wrote this script to generate a list of numbers from a predefined list, with no consecutive items, until their sum reaches a certain value. I'm now wondering how I might be able to make the function repeat, if the remainder of the sum and the value are below a certain amount.

Here is the code:

```
import random

spans = [120, 125, 240, 380, 315, 320, 405, 450]
length = 1000

def addVals(nums,total):
    sum = 0
    vals = []
    i = 0
    while sum<=total:
        if len(vals) == 0:
            i = random.choice(nums)
            vals.append(i)
            sum+=i
            last = i
        else:
            nums.pop(nums.index(last))
            i = random.choice(nums)
            vals.append(i)
            nums.append(last)
            last = i
            sum+=i
    return vals

valList =  addVals(spans,length)
valSum = sum(valList)
valLeft = valSum - length

print valList
print valSum
print valLeft
```

So if a run of that code gives me:

```
[315, 120, 320, 380]
1135
135
```

I'd like to rerun the function if the remainder (valLeft) is greater than 100. I tried using if and using while, but 'if' gave me errors, and 'while' got hung up. Any ideas and/or links to potential solutions would be greatly appreciated! Would also gladly accept any criticism of the way my script is written as is, particularly the method I used to avoid consecutive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to rewrite your code in a cleaner way

```
import random

spans = [120, 125, 240, 380, 315, 320, 405, 450]
length = 1000

def addVals(nums,total):
    vals = []
    p = last = sum = 0
    while sum <= total:
        while last == p:
            p = random.choice(nums)
        sum += p
        vals.append(p)
        last = p
    return vals


valLeft = length
while valLeft >= 100:
    valList = addVals(spans,length)
    valSum = sum(valList)
    valLeft = valSum - length

print valList
print valSum
print valLeft
```

I think it works as you were expecting. 
Your code had one flaw, I don't think you notice that the pop method is actually changing your array, and it will eventually run out of elements. I don't think that was intended.

That's why I added another while to keep getting random choices until it gets one different from the last one.

Hope you like it.

Comment: Wow! This appears to be doing it. Do you mind explaining the `valLeft = length` portion? I only ask because I would've thought that would be overwriting my existing length parameter... but I must be wrong on that. Thanks so much for your time already.

Comment: I just set my valLeft controller to a number I assumed it would be bigger than 100.

Just to make sure it would enter the loop the first time. 

It work just fine if you put it `valLeft = 101` instead

Comment: Also do you mind explaining this bit to me? `p = last = sum = 0` I am almost wrapping my brain around its purpose but it is also simultaneously confusing me, haha

Comment: It's not changing your length parameter, no worries. 
You are just creating a new variable with the same value.

Comment: I initialized all three variables with value 0 at the same time.
It's the same as 
`p = 0`
`last = 0`
`sum = 0`

Comment: Wow that makes so much sense (sorry my second comment occurred before I saw your first reply) Thank you so much. I believe I was overthinking things a bit there

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thank you a bunch Marcel. This was very helpful for my solution and learning :)

Comment: @Amy My advice, don't use builtin names for variables, e.g. `sum`.  Consider `total` or `sum_`

Comment: @pylang thank you that is good advice. I hadn't scripted this in a Python only environment and added those variables* after the fact in a rush to create this post, but I probably would have overlooked that anyway.Thank you so much :)

Comment: @marcelotokarnia it works perfectly and now I am uncertain as why I cannot modify this to work with >= and <=. Should I make a new post? Do you mind looking at this for me?

Comment: Don't understand your question. What do you want to modify ?

Comment: @marcelotokarnia sorry - I am not used to hitting enter and my comment sending before reevaluation, lol. I wanted to modify it to rerun if the remainder is greater than a certain value AND less than a certain value. I cannot get it to work by modifying as simply as I expected it to be. I might be writing it incorrectly. I tried changing `while valLeft >= 100:` to `while valLeft <=50 and valLef >= 100` and it did not work, so not sure why.  Let me know if this should be a new post in itself.

Comment: You probably just swapped the operators by mistake, this way you are verifying if it is smaller than 50 and greater than 100 ... no number satisfies this condition.

You should do `while valLeft >= 50 and valLeft <= 100`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add a `while` loop right above your print statements that just reruns `addVals()` until `valLeft` is less than or equal to 100:

```
while valLeft>100:
    valList =  addVals(spans,length)
    valSum = sum(valList)
    valLeft = valSum - length
```

The issue with this is if there is no possible way to get an array with a sum of `length` with a `valLeft` of less than 100 then you enter an infinite while loop.

For example: `spans = [ 410, 415, 405, 400, 450]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer - I see that that would be an issue. Would you recommend a try/except case then that assesses the input values?